# How to concatenate/merge data of three textfiles into one textfiles in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, text-files, concatenation

I'm having a big trouble. I'd like to concatenate data of multiple textfiles  into another textfiles. But I cannot. can you help me ? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read each file one by one,

```
NSString *firstFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:<your file path>
                                                       encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                          error:nil];

//Similarly read other files, and store them in secondFileContent and thirdFileContent.

//now concatenate all to form one big string.
NSString *bigString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-First File- \n%@ \n-Second File- \n%@\n-Third File-\n%@",firstFileContent, secondFileContent, thirdFileContent];

//write to file, create a new one
[bigString writeToFile:<path to write>
            atomically:YES
              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                 error:nil];
```

**Edit 1** :

As per your comment that your file is in DocumentDirectory use this code :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:<your file name>];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: what is the output of `firstFileContent`?

Comment: my textfiles were in documentsdirectory so instead of accessing from there ..i was using   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: ofType:];for accessing it i,e, i got it wrong thatswhy output for filecontents was NULL .But now i got it right.Thanks for your time.

Comment: :ye thanks got it..but i have one quesn ..I have called all textfile creation method from buttoncontrol and concatenate method  too so when i clicked all the button at first time..only first textfile(its content)is created and all other textfiles are empty..2nd time clicked all textfile created and concatenated too..whats the problem?

Comment: post a new question with codes, so that we can help you. And don't forget to link this question there.

Comment: you are always creating same `myFile1.txt`.

Comment: No..myfile2.txt,myfile3.txt

Answer (score 1):

First load content of file in `NSString` and use following code:

```
   NSString *strConcatenate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", textfiles1, textfiles2, textfiles3];    
   NSLog(@"%@", strConcatenate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to load the content of the files into `NSMutableString` and concatenate them :

```
NSMutableString *myString = @"Content of the first file";
NSString *test = [myString stringByAppendingString:@" content of the second file"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the text files in from the bundle and then append them, once you have that then write it back out. I wrote this example and I hope you can learn from it.

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

NSArray *textFiles = @[ @"textfile1", @"textfile2", @"textfile3" ];

for (NSString *textFileName in textFiles) {

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:textFileName 
                                                   ofType:@"txt"];

  NSError *error = nil;
  NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];

  if (content) {
    [mutableString appendFormat:@"%@\n", content];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
  }

}

NSLog(@"%@", mutableString);

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL result = [mutableString writeToFile:@"concatenated_file.txt" atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];

if (!result) {
  NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```